# R Shiny alternate actionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple app that each time click `plus1`, the value of x increases by 1, and each time click `plus10`, the value of x increases by 10. But I want `plus10` can only be valid after `plus1` is clicked. And after `plus1` is clicked, `plus10` can only be clicked once before being invalid again, which would require another click of `plus1` to make it valid. So basically I want the user to click those two buttons alternately, with `plus1` needs to be clicked first when the app is launched. Ideally, a warning would be given to the user if the user tried to click `plus10` without clicking `plus1` first: "Please click plus1 first".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("plus1", "+ 1"),
  actionButton("plus10", "+ 10"),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$plus1,{
    x(x()+1) # increment x by 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plus10,{
    x(x()+10) # increment x by 1
  })
  
  output$value = renderText(x())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("plus1", "+ 1"),
  disabled(actionButton("plus10", "+ 10")),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$plus1,{
    x(x() +1 )
    disable('plus1')
    enable('plus10')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plus10, {
    x(x() + 10)
    enable('plus1')
    disable('plus10')
  })
  
  output$value <- renderText({x()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: love this package! Have other functions in the package that are useful as well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want, but why do you want this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("plus1", "+ 1"),
    actionButton("plus10", "+ 10"),
    textOutput("value"),
    textOutput("warning")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    x = reactiveValues(x=0,click1=TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$plus1,{
        if (x$click1) {
            x$x <- x$x+1 # increment x by 1
            x$click1 <- !x$click1
        } else {
            output$warning <- renderText({"Please click plus10 first"})
        }
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$plus10,{
        if (!x$click1) {
            x$x <- x$x+10 # increment x by 10
            x$click1 <- !x$click1
        } else {
            output$warning <- renderText({"Please click plus1 first"})
        }
    })
    
    output$value = renderText(x$x)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Let me know if explanation needed

Comment: This is just a simplified version for what I'm trying to do, but it's easier to map out the problem in this way. I have two buttons in the app, one is called "approve" and the other is "Next Page". And I don't want the user to proceed to next page if they haven't approved the document.

Comment: Excellent answer, I didn't know you can use reactive values like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just another reactive value to track whether or not the user can add 10

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("plus1", "+ 1"),
  actionButton("plus10", "+ 10"),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactiveVal(0)
  canPlus10 <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$plus1,{
    x(x()+1) # increment x by 1
    canPlus10(TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plus10,{
    if (canPlus10()) {
      x(x()+10) # increment x by 10
    } else {
      showNotification("Please click +1 first")
    }
    canPlus10(FALSE)
  })
  
  output$value = renderText(x())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is beautiful answer, can be easily scalable to more complicated apps with this problem. Your answer however the user can click on the plus1 button multiple times, and my intention is the user can only click it once. But using your logic, I manage to create another reactive value called canPlus1 = reactiveVal(TRUE), and using some logic in the if else statement to make it work. Thanks!